# Dependency error while installing MariaDB10.1 on RHEL 7.1

Tags: mariadb, redhat, yum, rhel

I am trying to install MariaDB 10.1 on RHEL 7.1 using following link
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=Fibergrid&distro=RedHat&distro_release=rhel7-amd64--rhel7&version=10.1
I am Getting following error while installing

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.20-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.061-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 1:2.061-4.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Is there really no libsystemd.so.0 for RHEL 7.1? There is no RHEL 7.1 x86_64 builder in the lab, the packages are actually built on CentOS 7, maybe something is different.

Comment: I would suggest using MariaDB packaged as a [Software Collection](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html-single/2.3_Release_Notes/index.html#sect-RHSCL-Features).

Comment: If there is indeed no such library for RHEL 7.1 in default repos, please also file a bug report at [JIRA](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the same [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20484) was solved by *Docker* community

Their solution was to upgrade **RHEL** to **7.2** version and these problems should be gone

I had the same issue with *Amazon Linux*, but solution is different (solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511474/check-mk-installation-failed-dependencies-mariadb-python-reportlab-libgsf/42550101#42550101))

Good luck.