# Check-mk installation. Failed dependencies (Mariadb, Python-reportlab, libgsf)

Tags: amazon-ec2, mariadb, rpm, nagios, check-mk

I have problem with installation check_mk on amazon-ec2.

I have already installed nagios core successfully and I try now install check_mk plugin by rpm:

```
rpm -ivh check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64.rpm
```

Rpm stop and return list of needed dependencies for installation. Most of them I installed successfully but I have problem with rest of it.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    mariadb-server is needed by check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64
    python-reportlab is needed by check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64
    libgsf is needed by check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64
```

**Mariadb**

I followed instruction from site https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/

Next I created MariaDB.repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory with content:

```
# MariaDB 10.1 RedHat repository list - created 2017-02-28 11:57 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/rhel7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

After that I tried install MariaDB by command:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

In result I got follow errors

```
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.21-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.21-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
```

So I tried install systemd, in result I got:

```
configure: error: *** libmount support required but libraries not found
```

when I tried install it by yum I received:

```
Package libmount-2.23.2-26.27.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**Python-reportlab**

```
rpm -Uvh python-reportlab-3.1.8-5.fc23.x86_64.rpm 
warning: python-reportlab-3.1.8-5.fc23.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 34ec9cba: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    python-pillow is needed by python-reportlab-3.1.8-5.fc23.x86_64


rpm -Uvh python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686.rpm
warning: python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 34ec9cba: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libfreetype.so.6 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libjpeg.so.62 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    liblcms2.so.2 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libopenjp2.so.7 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libtiff.so.5 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0) is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libwebp.so.5 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libwebpdemux.so.1 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libwebpmux.so.1 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686
    libz.so.1 is needed by python-pillow-3.0.0-1.fc23.i686


 rpm -Uvh glibc-2.24-3.fc25.i686.rpm 
warning: glibc-2.24-3.fc25.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fdb19c98: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc-common = 2.24-3.fc25 is needed by glibc-2.24-3.fc25.i686
    glibc-langpack = 2.24-3.fc25 is needed by glibc-2.24-3.fc25.i686


rpm -ivh glibc-common-2.25-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm 
warning: glibc-common-2.25-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 64dab85d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/bash is needed by glibc-common-2.25-1.fc26.x86_64
    glibc = 2.25-1.fc26 is needed by glibc-common-2.25-1.fc26.x86_64
```

**libgsf**

I installed it from source (libgsf-1.14.0) successfully, nevertheless when I trying use rpm check-mk installation command I see it in failed dependencies. Can I somehow add it to rpm list manually?

I will be grateful for any clue. I struggle with it too long without progress.

os-release:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"

Architecture:          x86_64
```

28.02.2017     EDIT:

Successfully I installed MariaDB:

```
Package MariaDB-server-10.1.21-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version 
Package MariaDB-client-10.1.21-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

but still I get failed dependencies:

```
rpm -Uvh check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64.rpm 

error: Failed dependencies: 
mariadb-server is needed by check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64 
python-reportlab is needed by check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64 
libgsf is needed by check-mk-raw-1.2.8p17-el7-40.x86_64 how resolve it?
```

01.03.2017     EDIT:

Finally I installed version for rhel6 and it's working now.

Comment: I found similar problem with mariadb, but It is unsolved [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481641/dependency-error-while-installing-mariadb10-1-on-rhel-7-1)

Comment: Another issue like that [How to install MariaDB on Redhat Enterprise Linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/768355/how-to-install-mariadb-on-redhat-enterprise-linux/768387#768387?newreg=51883778f7374e1c955bdf9a4dc228da) and [YUM to install MariaDB and the reasons given in the AWS EC2](https://github.com/LempStacker/DatabaseRelated/blob/master/MariaDB/Backup/LearningNotesBackup/2015.10.20_%E5%9C%A8AWS%20EC2%E4%B8%ADYUM%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9DMariaDB%E5%A0%B1%E9%8C%AF%E5%8F%8A%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can help with **MariaDB**, today I encountered with the same issue.

I was trying to install the latest *MariaDB 10.1* and I got the same error as you there. *Docker* community had this issue some time ago and they just upgraded *RHEL 7.1* to newer version and all the problems were gone.

As we all know, with *Amazon Linux* it's not so simple.

So I followed these steps and I was able to install *MariaDB 5.5* (for my purposes it was OK)

- Modify your **MariaDB.repo** file with this content (actually, only *baseurl* changes):

  ```
  [mariadb]
  name = MariaDB
  baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
  gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
  gpgcheck=1
  ```
- Clean repos metadata

  ```
  sudo yum clean metadata
  ```
- Finally, try to install *MariaDB* server and client

  ```
  sudo yum install -y MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
  ```

It worked very well for me. Good luck.

Comment: I solve it in the same way. I don't know why but for my version of aws more appropriate is version for rhel6 than rhel7.

Comment: @StanisławL. I'm not sure, but possibly the same here. That is the most annoying thing about developing with AWS. AWS provides _MariaDB 10.1_ image instance, but it's impossible to use the latest version in Amazon Linux for development purposes